# Can a function be made to pull column values from same row?

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

I have created a formula of formulas. The idea is I am studying baseball statistics and sabermetrics. I have a series of computations that helps me find the winning probability of a team. The final formula that incorporates several other formulas looks as such:

```
GameSBWprobabilityPO <- function(HomeTeam, HomePitcher, AwayTeam, AwayPitcher, season, date){
  Hometeam <- GameSBWteamprobsum(HomeTeam, HomePitcher, season, date)
  Awayteam <- GameSBWteamprobsum(AwayTeam, AwayPitcher, season, date)
  TOTprob  <- sum(Hometeam, Awayteam)
  HTWp     <- (Hometeam/TOTprob)
  ATWp     <- (Awayteam/TOTprob)
  return(HTWp)
}
```

I'm wondering if theres a way I could make it simply

```
<- function(date, HomeTeam)
```

And have R auto populate the other variables which are all contained in the same row. The Column names for these variables are named as such:

```
HomeTeam = team1
HomePitcher = pitcher1
AwayTeam = team2
AwayPitcher = pitcher2
season = season
date = date
```

Also, how do I edit output? Currently it just returns the probability that the hometeam wins based on my formula:

```
[1] 0.5167891
```

But I would love to figure out how to make it appear as each teams probability against each other in the output for current example:

```
[1] BOS 51.46%, HOU 48.54%
```

Or anything similar to that.
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I like using the data.table package for things like this. I don't know what your "GameSBWteamprobsum" function does, so here is a simplified solution using data.table's chaining:

```
library(data.table)

GameSBWteamprobsum <- function(x, ...){2*x}

DT <- data.table(HomeTeam=runif(10,1,10), HomePitcher=runif(10,1,10), AwayTeam=runif(10,1,10), AwayPitcher=runif(10,1,10), season=runif(10,1,10), date=runif(10,1,10))

DT[, "Hometeam" := GameSBWteamprobsum(HomeTeam, HomePitcher, season, date)][
  , "AwayTeam" := GameSBWteamprobsum(AwayTeam, AwayPitcher, season, date)][
    , "TOTprob" := sum(Hometeam, AwayTeam)][
      , "HTWp" := Hometeam/TOTprob][
        , "ATWp" := AwayTeam/TOTprob]

DT
```

You might want to have a look at the chaining section [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf)

EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------------

Sure, you can pass a row or a subset of rows to your function based on a condition for one or multiple columns:

```
library(data.table)

GameSBWteamprobsum <- function(x){print(x)}

DT <- data.table(HomeTeam=LETTERS[1:10], HomePitcher=runif(10,1,10), AwayTeam=runif(10,1,10), AwayPitcher=runif(10,1,10), season=runif(10,1,10), date=runif(10,1,10))

GameSBWteamprobsum(DT[HomeTeam == "A"])
```

Comment: The data table (mlb_elo) looks like this: `date | season | neutral | playoff | team1 | team 2 | pitcher1 | pitcher2 | score1 | score 2` so an example is a line for today's game would say `2017-10-18 | 2018 | FALSE | HOU | BOS | Justin Verlander | David Price | 1 | 4` with 12 more columns interspersed in the data frame giving elo_probabilitys ratings and such. In order to run the function I have to write `GameSBWprobabilityPO("HOU", "Justin Verlander", "BOS", "David Price", "2018", "2017-10-18")` every time.

Comment: I was hoping to get it so that I would only write per say `GameSBWprobabilityPO("2017-10-18", "HOU")` and it would identify that row seeing as the date and home team only equate to a singular possible row. now I can't just subset the data frame to only have that row because they need the full table, however, anywhere it says any of `HomeTeam, HomePitcher, AwayTeam, AwayPitcher, season, date` it would auto-fill those from the row so I don't have to write so many variables constantly.

Comment: Please see my edit. Sorry but rebuilding your data-structure takes too much time. Provide it as code if you want others to use it.